# What's going on with my apache2?

Tags: apache

I have an apache server that I have set up behind my home firewall as a reverse proxy.  Requests come in and, depending on the domain name, get pushed off to other http servers.  Works fine.

But when I look at the log, I am getting pounded with all kinds of other foreign requests bouncing off the proxy server.  Here are the latest examples:

```
192.187.102.34 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5307684 HTTP/1.0" 302 837 "http://www.mobizill.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; AOL 8.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
104.250.146.5 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://bh.contextweb.com/bh/visitormatch?tag=253758&pid=558088 HTTP/1.0" 200 5375 "http://www.tvzhou.com/category/entertainment/celebs" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.861.0 Safari/535.2"
198.204.239.243 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://pixel.mathtag.com/sync/js?sync=auto&mm_bnc&mm_bct HTTP/1.0" 200 1145 "http://www.abdgames.com/playground-of-the-gods/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
216.244.79.211 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://www.advantageglobalmarketing.com/show.php?z=15&w=0&pl=1292&ad_type=0&charset=0&top_space=0&shape=0&c_border=0&c_background=0&page_background=0&c_text1=0&c_text2=0&c_text3=0&c_text4=0&c_text5=0&c_text6=0&c_text7=0&c_text8=0&c_text9=0&c_text10=0&j=1&code=1446201551474 HTTP/1.0" 200 1410 "http://www.wishbestgames.com/showgame/5890/Freegear_Z.html" "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; ru) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.11"
23.89.252.103 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5705662 HTTP/1.0" 302 837 "http://www.tourismest.com/?p=400" "Mozilla/4.0 (MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
23.244.78.246 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://px.owneriq.net/ecc?redir=http%3a%2f%2fwww.burstnet.com%2fuser%2f2%2fbidder_id%3d77253%26bidder_user_id%3dQ4995167421212624353%26cookie_duration%3d30&uid=Q4995167421212624353&ref=%2Fead HTTP/1.0" 302 632 "http://www.uclabruins.com/AdMonitor.dbml?SPSID=749825&SPID=126913&DB_OEM_ID=30500&MONITOR_AD_ID=1303197" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)"
104.202.31.47 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5731706 HTTP/1.0" 302 837 "http://www.yamidoo.com/?p=1160" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)"
74.222.130.10 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://my.mobfox.com/request.php?c.mraid=1&c_customevents=1&r_type=banner&o_iosadvidlimit=0&rt=iphone_app&u=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28iPhone%3B+CPU+iPhone+OS+8_3+like+Mac+OS+X%29+AppleWebKit%2F600.1.4+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F8.0+Mobile%2F12F70+Safari%2F600.1.4&u_wv=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28iPhone%3B+CPU+iPhone+OS+8_3+like+Mac+OS+X%29+AppleWebKit%2F600.1.4+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F8.0+Mobile%2F12F70+Safari%2F600.1.4&u_br=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28iPhone%3B+CPU+iPhone+OS+8_3+like+Mac+OS+X%29+AppleWebKit%2F600.1.4+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F8.0+Mobile%2F12F70+Safari%2F600.1.4&o_iosadvid=3B1A70DA-6B94-1799-2DE5-E0E1F7AC316C&v=6.0.0&s=9a7f211472dd8d72782c671d3f8adc4e&iphone_osversion=8.3&spot_id=&r_random=4087&adspace.width=320&adspace.height=50&adspace.strict=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1804 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12F70 Safari/600.1.4"
23.89.252.100 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://ib.adnxs.com/bounce?%2Fttj%3Fid%3D5705662 HTTP/1.0" 200 459 "http://www.tourismest.com/?p=956" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8"
74.91.28.91 - - [30/Oct/2015:11:37:13 -0700] "GET http://pixel.mathtag.com/sync/js?sync=auto&mm_bnc&mm_bct HTTP/1.0" 200 1142 "http://www.calbears.com/SportSelect.dbml?ATCLID=208216429&DB_LANG=C&DB_OEM_ID=30100&SPID=126521&SPSID=749467" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.133 Safari/534.16"
```

I have something configured wrong... but cannot figure out what.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName crossroad.blah.com

    ServerAdmin blah@blah.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a.bling.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://a.int.blah.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://a.int.blah.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName b.booger.org
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://b.int.blah.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://a.int.blah.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName c.bigger.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://c.int.blah.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://c.int.blah.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you share your Apache rev-proxy configuration?

Comment: Sorry.. missed your request.  Here is it:

Comment: just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Spent the weekend working on this.  Apparently its called referrer spam and I got hit badly.  Luckily this is just a proxy server and I can send all of the traffic not destined for one of my virtual hosts to the bit bucket by making the following entry my first entry in my conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName default
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        CustomLog /dev/null common
        ErrorLog  /dev/null
</VirtualHost>
```